# How to concat two arrays from an object with same data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, logic, concatenation

I have an array of objects like this:

```
  const array = [
  {
    dates: [
      {
        date: "01",
        test: "FO",
      },
      {
        date: "07",
        test: "AB",
      },
    ],
    login: "TESTE.TESTE",
  },
  {
    dates: [
      {
        date: "02",
        test: "AB",
      },
      {
        date: "04",
        test: "FO",
      },
    ],
    login: "TESTE.TESTE",
  },
];
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
    const array = [ 
  {
    dates: [
      {
        date: "01",
        test: "FO",
      },
      {
        date: "02",
        test: "AB",
      },
      {
        date: "04",
        test: "FO",
      },
      {
        date: "07",
        test: "AB",
      },
    ],
    login: "TESTE.TESTE",
  },
];
```

Basicaly I want to concat the objects with same 'login' property, and concat theirs 'dates' array and then fill it with the missing days, like: 01, 02, 03....31

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? `for`, `if` and `.push()` should be all you need.

Comment: Yes, but I could not solve It yet

Comment: you can reduce to group by login

Comment: We're here to help you with your script, not to write it completely -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, just a simple `reduce` with conditional `push`.

```js
const array = [
  {
    dates: [{ date: "01", test: "FO" }, { date: "07", test: "AB" }],
    login: "TESTE.TESTE"
  },
  {
    dates: [{ date: "02", test: "AB" }, { date: "04", test: "FO" }],
    login: "TESTE.TESTE"
  }
];

const result = array.reduce((res, curr) => {
  const found = res.find(el => el.login === curr.login);
  if (found) {
    found.dates.push(...curr.dates);
  } else {
    res.push(curr);
  }
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```